# SSL error while recording app using jmeter

Tags: android, jmeter

Below is the error I am getting while I try to record mobile app - Android.

```
Problem with SSL certificate for 'Application URL'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown.
```

Below are the things I have taken care of:

1. I have installed the certificate on the device.
2. Jmeter & App are running on the same network.

Anybody has faced the same issue, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you installed JMeter Certificate as a Trusted CA Authority and not as regular certificate.

Also check you are using last JMeter version and a JDK8.

Comment: I'm using Jmeter version 3.2 & How do i install jmeter certificate as a trusted CA Authority. I am using android device to record.

Comment: Upgrade to JMeter 4.0 and reinstall the new certificate . In 4.0 version the certificate is better. For installation follow this: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_installing_root_CA_android.html

Comment: Thanks. I am still getting the same error.  Also, I get this error "Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore".

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. you need to start the recorder, it will generate the cert file then you can install

Comment: While recording, in the results I'm getting below error:       javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source) & Reponse message is " Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
**ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy certificate**"